# What is the reason for receiving jdbc error when attempting SonarQube 5.6 install

Tags: installation, upgrade, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube5.6

We are going from SonarQube-4.5.7 to SonarQube -5.6. While starting Sonar after the install, the sonar.log captures this error:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.projects' and the index name 'projects_uuid'. The duplicate key value is (xxxxxxx).: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [projects_uuid] ON [projects] ([uuid])
```

I have looked at other issues that refer to the first portion of this error, but those point to issues with a plugin. We have removed the plugins to rule out the possibility of being the issue. Is it still looking at plugin information in the database? Or is it really error due to a duplicate key of sorts in a table? If so, what is the best way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to the database not being updated with the proper collation for the VARCHAR columns. It needs to be *Latin1_General_CS_AS*. The key was considered a duplicate to another, without using the case sensitivity it needed to have.